# Not getting data using useEffect in react but get endpoint is working as tested using postman

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to get data from Mongo DB using fetch GET request. I am using `useEffect` to get data as shown below.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setComplaints } from "state";
import Complaint from "./Complaint";

const AllComplaints = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const complaints = useSelector((state) => state.complaints);

    const { role } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
    const isAdmin = role === "admin";

    const getComplaints = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(
            "http://localhost:3001/student/complaints",
            {
                method: "GET",
            }
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        dispatch(setComplaints({ complaints: data }));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getComplaints();
    }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

    console.log(complaints);

    return (
        <>
            {complaints.map(
                ({
                    _id,
                    fullName,
                    email,
                    hostel,
                    room,
                    description,
                    picturePath,
                    upvotes,
                    downvotes,
                    resolved,
                }) => (
                    <Complaint
                        key={_id}
                        complaintId={_id}
                        fullName={fullName}
                        hostel={hostel}
                        room={room}
                        description={description}
                        picturePath={picturePath}
                        upvotes={upvotes}
                        downvotes={downvotes}
                        resolved={resolved}
                        isAdmin={isAdmin}
                    />
                )
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export default AllComplaints;
```

On starting the app it gives error that `complaints.map` is not defined. I presume the problem is with `useEffect` and getting and setting the data to complaints because the endpoint is working normal as tested using Postman.

Code of `setComplaints` in state/index.js:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    user: null,
    token: null,
    notifs: [],
    complaints: [],
};

export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setLogin: (state, action) => {
            state.user = action.payload.user;
            state.token = action.payload.token;
        },
        setLogout: (state) => {
            state.user = null;
            state.token = null;
        },
        setNotifs: (state, action) => {
            state.notifs = action.payload.notifs;
        },
        setComplaints: (state, action) => {
            state.complaints = action.payload.complaints;
        },
    },
});

export const {
  setLogin,
  setLogout,
  setNotifs,
  setComplaints
} = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

What can I do? I tried making the function `async` in `useEffect` but still the same error.

Comment: Please include the code for the `setComplaints` function.

Comment: @R.M.Reza i have added the same. please look into it further

Comment: FWIW I don't believe the `useEffect` hook usage is related to the issue. The `complaints` array appears to be part of some "auth" state, but you are selecting `state.complaints` in the component. Is it perhaps supposed to be something more like `const complaints = useSelector((state) => state.auth.complaints);`? Please [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] that includes how the Redux store is created and provided to the app, including how the reducers are combined to create the state tree.

Comment: theres an update on the issue , it sometimes works fine but other times gives error.